# Getting error springOracleConfig &dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer circular dependancy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

```
    Hi Iam getting the error while upgrading the spring boot version from 2.2.6.RELEASE to 2.7.10 version.The error is : The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
```

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

```
    My SpringOracleConfig code class is :
    
    @Configuration
    public class SpringOracleConfig {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringOracleConfig.class);
    
        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;
        
        public static Map<String, ScheduleJobBean> scheduledJobs;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.vsession.osuser}")
        private String osUser;
    
        @Bean
        public HikariDataSource getHikariDataSource() {
    
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverclassName);
            hikariConfig.setUsername(userName);
            hikariConfig.setPassword(CRUtil.decryptPwd(password));
            hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceUrl);
            hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
            hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(connTimeout);
            hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(minIdle);
            hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
            hikariConfig.setDataSourceProperties(props);
    
            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    
            if (!hikariDataSource.isClosed()) {
                LOGGER.info("------> Oracle DB connection with successfull.");
            }
            return hikariDataSource;
    
        }
 
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("odsxxcrrfc")
        public JdbcTemplate odsJdbcTemplate() {
            return new JdbcTemplate(getHikariDataSource());
        }






     ┌─────┐
    |  springOracleConfig
    ↑     ↓
    |  dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]
    └─────┘
```

Iam getting this error even though i set spring.main.allow-circular-references = true in the properties file. Where the issue here,please help on this.How to resolve this error